# Xamarin Title bar text centered (Cross-platform)

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin, cross-platform

I've been working on this project, and its really been bothering me. I have this issuse where I can easily add text to my title bar, but i can't center it. All my code is written in either XAML / MVVM. The thing is, it needs to be cross-platform, So far i've only found guides how to do it specific for android devices.

[image: Title bar]

Heres is the example of my title bar right now. I want to center that text. I hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

It is centered by default on iOS and you would need to add a custom binding I guess to add the Android specific code for centering it.